# Upgrade to 18.04 to 17.10

Tags: upgrade, 18.04

I have been using Ubuntu for some time now. Tonight I decided to switch to the newest version 18.04 LTS via upgrade because the data is important to me. During the installation some "BIG or IMPORTANT s" errors occurred. First IBUS not installed or something like this then 2) UNITY-CONTROL-CENTER could not be installed. The last message via upgrading was the 18.04 couldn't be installed so the installation will be reversed. Doesn't reboot automatically, the Wifi don't work, don't want to shutdown using the menu. So I switch off. Now the Acer SF114-31-P5WW won't boot from neither version. I need to restore the previous version or in its defect to put to work the new version. Please advise

Comment: The first thing you can do is boot with a Live USB and copy your important files so you don't loose them if something goes wrong.

Comment: Thank you. Live USB using 18.04 or 17.10 does it matters?. The computer tries to boot and runs certain scripts some lines give error others not. At the end the last thing to get is a blinking cursor.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix is right: You must back up your data, any LiveUSB version of Ubuntu will do for that. There are many, many possible causes for your failed upgrade and you must provide much more detail of the exact errors for help with that. Since your system no longer boots, we gently suggest backing up your data and then doing a clean install of Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you both!!. Finally, I can recover my files and do a new fresh 18.04LTS installation.